# Number of turns needed to rewind a 4-pole motor as 2-pole

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine, winding

I'm wishing to rewind a 4-pole, 1/2 cv motor as a 2-pole motor for the same voltage rating.

Its stator has 32 slots, and the main winding looks like this:

[image]

It's a concentric winding, made of 4 identical units, and the first has turns as follows:

15 turns between slots 3 and 6,

27 turns between slots 2 and 7,

32 turns between slots 1 and 8

If I were to rewind it as 2-pole, the main winding would then look like this:

[image]

And my question is:

Would the number of turns be the same as before?

Should the units have 15, 27 and 32 turns in their concentric coils too?

Or, rather, a similar amount of turns to get a sinusoidally distrubted MMF

---